# Overriding new but telling unordered_map not to use it

Tags: c++, unordered-map, new-operator, allocator, placement-new

I'm writing a garbage collector for C/C++ as a programming exercise, and part of this involves globally overriding `new`. However, the garbage collector also uses an `unordered_map` (to store pointers to allocated blocks), and things will get seriously messed up if the map tries to use the overridden new (it will try to infinitely loop I think). To create it, I wanted to use placement new to avoid calling the overridden new:

```
void *buffer = malloc(sizeof(unordered_map<void *, mem_t *>));
unordered_map<void *, mem_t *> map = new(buffer) unordered_map<void *, mem_t *>();
```

(mem_t is a struct I've defined, but I don't think that's relevant.) When run, this code segfaults inside the unordered_map constructor. I thought using placement new would have fixed the problem, but apparently not. I am pretty sure that unordered_map is calling new internally. Will giving it an allocator (how do I do that?) fix this problem? If not, is this problem fixable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full declaration of [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), as well as of all STL containers, includes [`allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) as the last parameter:

```
template<class Key, class Ty, class Hash, class Pred, class Alloc>
    class unordered_map;
```

That's where a container gets memory for all its internal structures.
You probably want to implement your own allocator here. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_%28C%2B%2B%29) looks like a good starting point.

Comment: So I would need to create a class and implement all 8 methods listed at the bottom of this page (
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/) then? All I want is for it to directly use malloc (and free) without going through new (and delete) first.

Comment: Yes. Or see if you can reuse what your compiler has - say, GCC provides bunch of special allocators (they are all under `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext` on my mac)